# How to Set Record Level Security for particular Records

Tags: sharing-rule, role-hierarchy

How to set security setting if region equal north america then only that particular role can see and edit that opportunity not the other users roles.

For Now If Region is "North America" then "EMEA" Region Users also see "North America" Region Opportunity.

How I Restrict that.

Comment: Sharing and visibility is a _huge_ topic (there is a major certification exam on this area of knowledge). You'll get a better answer if you share what you've already done and set up in your org. If you're new to sharing and visibility, please consider completing the relevant Trailhead modules and working with an experienced architect. This is not something to guess your way through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Put OWD for Opportunity to private. (sharing settings)
- in your roles check "opportunity access" settings (maybe access is given based on account owner?)
- create a sharing role for opportunity based on territory and share to the right group (role) or public group

Alternatively have a look at Territories to see if it suits your needs: [Territory Management Concepts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=territories_def.htm&type=5)